# php open print browser

Tags: php

I found this code that downloads automatically the pdf file which is declared in the GET method.  Is there another php code that opens the browser print window and allow the user to just click print?  and can I use the same GET method?  Thanks

```
 <?php
$name = isset($_GET["name"])? trim($_GET["name"]): "";
if ($name && preg_match("/\.pdf$/i",$name) && file_exists($name)) {
    header ("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header ("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header ("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));
    header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
    readfile($name);
    exit;
}
?>
```

I also found this Javascript code but it only works with Chrome 
    `function printTrigger(elementId) 
     { var getMyFrame = document.getElementById(elementId); 
     getMyFrame.focus(); 
     getMyFrame.contentWindow.print(); }`

Comment: why do you need another code?

Comment: This code that I have saves a file on click, I would like a code to open the print browser instead of saving the file.

Comment: Can you put all your comments to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for `window.print()`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sending the document as an `octet-stream` with an `attachment` disposition (which will force the user to download it) simply load the PDF (using the proper `header('Content-type: application/pdf');`) in a hidden iframe on the page and then use the javascript `print()` function (targeting that frame).

Comment: I am not very good with Javascript code.  But I'll give it a try.

Comment: Once you've given it a try feel free to append your attempt to this question and ask for feedback